Using existing Vega Sankey Diagram template for dynamic Power BI visual
I have used this Sankey Diagram template to make my own kind of template: https://github.com/PBI-David/Deneb-Showcase/tree/main/Sankey%20Chart
I have changed the nodes and values of the links, I ran into several errors but I am stuck at this error: [Error} Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'index')
All I have changed are the nodes and values whilst trying to keep the rest of the code intact. I also want to make this more dynamic by uploading my own Excel with data, but it is not yet clear to me how exactly this needs to be formatted.
The sankey I want also needs to have 4 flows, 2 to the left node and 2 to the right node. These stand for the accumulative positive and negative energyflows through a surface (like a wall) throughout the year. Is this even possible in this Sankey Diagram?
Example Sankey Diagram
Here is also the example Excel file that I have used with sample data:
Nodes:
enter image description here
Links:
enter image description here
I have tried using ChatGPT / Perplexity to change the code but it does not give me the result I need. Sometimes I get a code that does not give any errors but then gives me no visual, it is just a blank space. I'm quite new to Deneb and Power BI in general, so still learning a lot!
